# How to make Coverity analyze secondary language

Tags: javascript, coverity

I would like [Coverity](https://scan.coverity.com) to analyze JavaScript code in this sample project: https://github.com/Skybladev2/AppVeyorTest

The primary language is set to C#, the secondary language is set to JavaScript:[image: Coverity language settings]

Coverity successfully found C# defect, but it can not find defect in [JavaScript file](https://github.com/Skybladev2/AppVeyorTest/blob/master/AppVeyorTest/JavaScript1.js):

```
var a = [];
var b = a[1];
var c = b();
```

What should I do with Coverity and/or project itself to detect this defect?

Answer (score 4):

What version of Coverity are you using? It it's a version that supports JavaScript (relatively new), then these commands should be sufficient to enable analysis for JavaScript and C#.

```
$ cov-configure --cs
$ cov-configure --javascript
```

Note that for JavaScript you need to tell cov-build where to find your .js files (e.g., `--fs-capture-search`). You may want to read the manual for this one.

Once you've captured the JavaScript source files (`cov-build` will report how many files it captured), the analysis will automatically analyze it for defects.

Comment: I'm using [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/installed-software#getting-the-list-of-installed-software), but have no idea what version of Coverity is installed there.
Where can I find a manual? [Community site](https://communities.coverity.com/community/developer-forums) is down., so it's extremely hard to find any help about Coverity.

Comment: I can see `Node: comp_lang Value: Non Compiled`, `Node: comp_generic Value: javascript` and `Node: file_include_pattern Value: ^.*\.js` when using Coverity 7.7.0.4 locally, but it does not write any more related to JavaScript in build log. Calling `cov-configure --javascript` results into `[WARNING] Configuration already exists for file regex ^.*\.js$ and it will not be updated.`

Comment: You have JavaScript configured then. What's your `cov-build` command? You need to inform it as to where to look for your JavaScript files, since these aren't compiled as part of a `make` command.

Comment: As for the Community site being down, I've pinged the relevant people inside Coverity. I'm not in that particular loop so I don't know the reason(s) why it's down, but I have received a response indicating that action is happening to address it. We certainly don't like making it difficult for people to do what they need to do.

Comment: My `cov-build` command is `& cov-build --dir cov-int "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Rebuild`. You can see it here: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/MikhailTymchukDX/appveyortest. Can you please provide me sample syntax for `cov-build` command to search for JavaScript files?

Comment: Before your build command (execution of MSBuild.exe), add `--fs-capture-search /path/to/javascript/files`. Assuming there's nothing overly special about your workflow, that should cause cov-build to search that location for JavaScript files and capture them for analysis.

e.g.,
  `$ cov-build --dir cov-int --fs-capture-search JSFiles "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Rebuild`

Comment: Thank you for that, now I can see this line in my log: `1 JavaScript compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis`. But no defects found for this code: https://github.com/MikhailTymchukDX/AppVeyorTest/blob/master/AppVeyorTest/JavaScript1.js
Is it intended?

Comment: I checked with our Analysis folks and they agree that this is a False Negative (defect we should be reporting but don't currently). They suggest you use this if you want to confirm that your JavaScript code is being analyzed: 
`var a = undefined;
a(); // or a.m;`

Comment: Thank you for response! Unfortunately, this defect was not found: https://scan.coverity.com/projects/mikhailtymchukdx-appveyortest?tab=overview Any clues why this happened?

Comment: I can't view that, so unfortunately no ideas. However if there's a defect we're not finding, I do encourage you to report it to Coverity support so that the appropriate teams can investigate it to find out why.

Comment: Unfortunately, support (support@coverity.com) rejects to help me unless I'm a paid user. So, while community site is down, stackoverflow is the only way of investigating this issue.